# How would I being to factor out this equation?

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, exponentiation

I'm stuck on trying to prove this Recursion Relation through mathematical induction:

We were given:

$cS(n−1)^2$

and was asked to find out the closed-form equation via the expand, guess, and verify method. Through that, I was able to get:

$S(n) = c^{2^{k}-1} \cdot S(n-k) \cdot 2^{k}$

and by substituting $k= n-1$, I got:

$S(n) = c^{2^{n-1}-1} \cdot S(n-(n-1)) \cdot 2^{n-1}$

Which is just:

$S(n) = c^{2^{n-1}-1} \cdot S(1) \cdot 2^{n-1}$

*The base case is true*

Induction Step:

$S(n+1) = c^{2^n-1} \cdot S(1) \cdot 2^n$ => *What I have to prove*

$S(n+1) = cS(n)^2 = c[c^{2^{n-1}-1} S(1) 2^{n-1}]^2$

I'm not quite sure how I would begin to square the above equation; I feel as though it's really simple and I'm going to keep trying to work out it as I post this, but any hints to get started would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: The first equality in the post is not a recurrence, but rather a non-recursive definition of $S(n)$. And the recurrence from the last equation does not match the previous definition. What exactly is it that's given, and what do you need to prove?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I forgot to add that. We were given: $cS(n-1)^2$. We then had to find it's closed-form equation through the expand, guess, verify method which I did and is the: $S(n) = c^{2^{n-1}-1} \cdot S(1) \cdot 2^{n-1}$. I'm trying to prove the first S(n+1) which is the: $S(n+1) = c^{2^n-1} S(1) 2^n$

Comment: Please edit that into the question, not as a comment, since that's essential information. Anyway, the problem is that the closed form you are trying to prove by induction is the wrong one. Did you maybe mean: $$S_n = c^{2^{n-1}-1} {S_1}^{2^{n-1}}$$

Comment: Is there any way I can contact you privately so I can show you all of my work?

Comment: Sorry, no, but by all means please edit any relevant information into the question. This is a public board, and you best increase your chances at good answers if you keep it out in the open loud and clear.

Comment: Okay I edited in my work without actually including the "Expand" section to save space. Everything that is on my paper should be on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (using $S_n$ for $S(n)$): write out the first few consecutive terms, then telescope all the way down to $S_1$ once the pattern emerges.

$$
\begin{align}
S_n & = c \cdot S_{n-1}^2 = c^{2-1} \cdot S_{n-1}^{2^1}\\
 & = c \cdot \big(c \cdot S_{n-2}^2\big)^2 = c^{2^2-1} \cdot S_{n-2}^{2^2} = \\
 & = c^{2^2-1} \cdot \big(c \cdot S_{n-3}^2\big)^{2^2} = c^{2^3-1} \cdot S_{n-3}^{2^3} = \\
 & \cdots \\
 & = c^{2^{n-1}-1} \cdot S_{1}^{2^{n-1}}
\end{align}
$$

To formally justify the "telescoping", prove by induction that:

$$
\begin{align}
S_{n+1} = c^{2^{n}-1} \cdot S_{1}^{2^{n}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I'm confused, I'm not trying to prove that equation? I'm trying to prove: $S(n+1) = c^{2^n-1} \cdot S(1) \cdot 2^n$ or are they the same thing?

Comment: @Sweetcharge Your equation is wrong, or at least it doesn't match the recursion you posted. For $S_1=1$ for example the first few terms of $S_n=c \cdot S_{n-1}^2$ are $(1, c, c^3, c^7, \cdots)$. Those don't match your equation, so you won't be able to prove it because it's the wrong equation.